# Nesting the app-header-layout

Tags: polymer

So I really like the scroll functionality that app-header-layout provides, and I'd like to use it within a confined space on my webapp. The trouble is, it keeps sticking to the top of the page, regardless of the dom I place it in. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Did you make your container div element position: relative?

Comment: That fixes it. Thanks!